# How do I close a form when windows media player finishes video playlist?

Tags: visual-studio, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a form where a button opens a dialogue box and the user can select multiple videos to play. The code puts the videos into a playlist and opens a new form with axwindowsmediaplayer embedded to play the video.

I am trying to close the player form when the playlist ends. I can close the form using a playstate change event if I only select one video, but can't figure out how to close the form for multiple video files in the playlist.

I have tried using timers to keep checking the play list, but have not had any luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction in closing a form after the video playlist ends?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your code as it is.

Comment: Thanks for answering sunny. I actually figured it out through some trial and error and tested to see if there was one video in the playlist and closed it based on a playstate of 1, or if there were multiple videos in the playlist, tested to see if the playstate was 10, or waiting. That fixed the problem for me.